# Displaying a JList in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have this piece of code, which I use to generate a `JList` with:

```
rightPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(20, 20)));
JList list = new JList(nameData);
list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
list.setLayoutOrientation(JList.HORIZONTAL_WRAP);
list.setVisibleRowCount(-1);
JScrollPane listScroller = new JScrollPane(list);
listScroller.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250, 80));
```

But even if the `nameData` has objects in it, it won't display the content of it as a list. Could you help me out and tell me what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, I just forgot to add `rightPanel.add(list);` at the end of the code, which adds the list to the panel.

Comment: Yeah, fixed that after posting the answer, forgot to edit it here.